# Issue reading in single files from a repo

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fstream

I am reading in files from a repo and I am having trouble compiling the code. My github partner(using a mac) has no issue with the code but when I clone his repo, I get this issue.

Background info: 
I recently moved into the Linux world and am running Elementary. Not sure if there could be an issue here since my other coding projects work, but it is background info.

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(std::__cxx11::string&)’
 infile.open(fullPath); // Open it up!


   In file included from AVL.cpp:6:0:
    /usr/include/c++/5/fstream:595:7: note: candidate: void std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
           open(const char* __s, ios_base::openmode __mode = ios_base::in)
           ^

/usr/include/c++/5/fstream:595:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Here's my function:

```
void AVL::parseFileInsert(string fullPath) {
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(fullPath); // Open it up!
    std::string line;
    char c;
    string word = "";
    //int jerry = 0;
    while (getline(infile, line))
    {
        // Iterate through the string one letter at a time.
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {

            c = line.at(i); // Get a char from string
            tolower(c);        
            // if it's NOT within these bounds, then it's not a character
            if (! ( ( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' ) || ( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' ) ) ) {

                //if word is NOT an empty string, insert word into bst
                if ( word != "" ) {
                    insert(word);
                    //jerry += 1;
                    //cout << jerry << endl;
                    //reset word string
                    word = "";
                }
            }
            else {
                word += string(1, c);
            }
         }
     }
};
```

Anything is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Obvious thing to try is `infile.open(fullPath.c_str()); // Open it up!`, but you seem to be using c++11 and it's been possible to open a file using a std::string for the file name since c++11, so I'm not sure.

Comment: what does `infile.open(fullPath);` return ?

Comment: @user: Code that doesn't compile will not run. Code that doesn't run will not return anything.

Comment: @john Yeah that was one of the original things I tried but to no avail. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [std::basic_fstream::open](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open) overload taking a `const std::string &` argument has been introduced in C++11. If the code compiles with one compiler but not another, it stands to reason that one compiler supports C++11 and the other doesn't (either by virtue of being too old, or by not specifying the C++ standard on the command line).

If you cannot switch to a C++11 compiler (or change the command line to enable C++11 support), you could simply change the line of code

```
infile.open(fullPath); // Open it up!
```

to

```
infile.open(fullPath.c_str()); // Open it up!
```

That doesn't change the semantics, with one exception: `std::string` supports embedded NUL characters, while the C-style string returned by `c_str()` does not. I'm not aware of a filesystem that allows embedded NUL characters in file/directory names, so that difference is of theoretical nature.

Comment: Thank you, I messed up by not having the "()" for the c_str. Thanks for clearing that up!